# Optimize Images retrieval from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a database which are "Setup" and "Items". "Setup" contain an image column with a data type of varbinary(max) and about 21 rows of records and "Items" also contains 12000 records. "Setup" table joins with "Items" table. The problem is when I run my join query with Image in it, it takes about 2 minutes but if I take the image column out of the query it takes 0 seconds. And if I maintain the image column but change the data type of image column to varbinary(1000) it takes 0 seconds. I want to use varbinary(max) as a data type for image column and execute the query in 0 seconds.

This is my query:

```
SELECT PS.[Item Image], P.[ItemId], P.SetupId, PS.Consumable, PS.Category, 
       PS.[Description], PS.Brand, PS.[Item Name], P.[Serial #], P.[Vendor Name], 
       P.[Date Received], [Location], S.[State] AS [Item State], Location 
FROM   PHOTOMATICS AS P 
       INNER JOIN PHOTOMATICSETUP AS PS 
         ON PS.[SetupId] = P.SetupId 
       LEFT JOIN PHOTOMATICSTATE AS S 
         ON S.PhotomaticId = P.ItemId ORDER BY P.ItemId
```

Comment: Images are relatively large, require lots of memory and require lots of bandwidth to transfer. Have you instead considered storing the images externally - such as on a web server, an S3 bucket with HTTP service, or a CDN - and only store the image URLs in the database? Do you really need to display 12,000 images in a single request?

Comment: I really need to display all the 12000 images

Comment: _I really need to display all the 12000 images_ Not at the same time, you certainly don't. Your question is without context but typically you retrieve the "blobs" separately and only when actually needed. Perhaps you need to store thumbnails and the full image - another possible optimization. But your idea of pulling resultsets containing large images in the same timeframe as the image-less query is nonsense.